# why do I can't extract data from response using grequests?

Tags: python, grequests

```
import grequests
import time
start_time = time.time()

sites = ['https://facebook.com' for x in range(5)]
data = {'a': 'b'}


responses = [grequests.get(u, data=data) for u in sites]

for response in responses:
    print(response)
    print(f'{response.text}')

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

When I try to get data by the `.text` method, I have an error:

```
AttributeError: 'AsyncRequest' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Even If I try to get `status_code` I have the same error with missing the attribute

The command to fix that I've searched `pip3 install --upgrade gevent==1.1rc3` returning me an error: `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` into  `5 | #include "Python.h"`

Comment: it seems it uses some C/C++ code and it needs Python source code (or only header files .h) to compile it. On Linux (Mint/Ubuntu/Debia) it would need to install `python3-dev` to get `Python.h` (`apt install python3-dev`) but I don't know how to do it on other systems.

Comment: if you run `async` function then it may need `await` to wait for result - maybe somethink like this will work `text = await response.text`. But this may need to run in function which uses `async`

Answer (score 0):

When module use async then it may run code in separated thread and it doesn't wait for result but it gives you object which you can later use to check if there is already result. In some modules you may use `await` to wait for result (but this works only inside `async` function and it needs to run `async` loop) but some modules have special functions to wait for results.

And `grequests` has also special function for this - which you should see in [official examples](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests)

```
responses = grequests.map(responses)
```

If you use it then you get list of objects `<Response>`. Without `map()` you get only list of objects `<grequests.AsyncRequest>`

---

Minimal working example:

```
import grequests
import time

start_time = time.time()


sites = ['https://facebook.com' for x in range(5)]
data = {'a': 'b'}

responses = [grequests.get(u, data=data) for u in sites]

# wait for all results
responses = grequests.map(responses)

for response in responses:
    print('response:', response)
    print('status_code:', response.status_code)
    print('text:', response.text)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```